# Turning off vibration on Huawei P9 lite

Tags: settings, huawei

My Huawei P9 lite vibrates when it goes to sleep after a short period of inactivity. How can I turn off the vibration?

Comment: Aren't there any settings like "Sound" or "Vibration intensity" that you can adjust?

Comment: On the Internet, it says Settings --> Sound --> Vibration Intensity. But there is no "vibration intensity" on my mobile ... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Do Not Disturb](https://www.google.com.sg/amp/www.greenbot.com/article/2995581/android/take-control-of-notifications-with-android-marshmallows-do-not-disturb-feature.amp.html) or silent hour mode of Android.

You will be able to set the window in which the phone will vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

**How To Turn Off Huawei P9 Vibration:**

1. Go to Settings
2. Select on Sound
3. Select Vibration Intensity

**Otherwise I think your device is infected with a virus**

Comment: There is no vibration intensity option on my mobile :-(